# How to return asynchronous calls in JavaScript with two callbacks (WIX corvid)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, velo

The following asynchronous function returns 2 callbacks, so I did what I usually do to return the response

1. Added return before the fetch
2. Added return before the result (`json.access_token`)

but this time `console.log(httpResponse, 'fetch json')` is undefined on the console and `console.log(json.access_token)` return the right value.

*What do I need to change?*

**From client**

```
GetJSON(NewURLCode).then(httpResponse => {
  console.log(httpResponse, 'fetch json')
}
```

**From Server**

```
GetJSON(NewURLCode){
  return fetch("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    'body': data
  }).then((httpResponse) => {
    if (httpResponse.ok) {
      return httpResponse.json();
    } else {
      return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
    }
  }).then((json) => { 
    console.log(json.access_token)
    return json.access_token
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

*Unlike the previous function, the following function has only one promise and returns the right object from the client*

**client**

```
insert_coll ('Token',toInsert).then((ins_result) => {consule.log(ins_result)}
```

**Backend**

```
insert_coll{
return wixData.update(myCollection, toUpdate, options)
.then( ( results) => {
let item = results; //see item below
return results

} )
.catch( (err) => {
let errorMsg = err;
} );

} 
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `return`s in front of `httpResponse.json();` and `Promise.reject(…)`

Comment: You aren't `return`ing `httpResponse.json()` - or `Promise.reject()` in your first then block

Comment: I edit my Q and added a return statement before `httpResponse.json()` but continue to get null on the client console and JSON on the server console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was not accrued because of the return statement, I added a return before `httpResponse.json();`

It caused because the WIX onReady component called twice...

So for solving this issue I used the following [WIX solution](https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-about-the-page-rendering-process) :

```
$w.onReady(function () {
  if (wixWindow.rendering.env === "browser") {

//your code
}})
```

Answer (score -3):

You can return that **fetch** itself, and handle those stuffs in client.
Like,

**Server**

```
GetJSON(NewURLCode){
  return fetch("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    'body': data
  });
}
```

**Client**

```
GetJSON(NewURLCode).then(httpResponse => {
    if (httpResponse.ok) {
      httpResponse.json();
    } else {
      Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
    }
  }).then((json) => { 
    console.log(json.access_token)
    return json.access_token
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Otherwise, just return a **Promise** after those are resolved in the server. Like,

**Server**

```
async GetJSON(NewURLCode){
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const httpResponse= await fetch("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", {
                "method": "post",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                'body': data
           });

           if (httpResponse.ok) {
              const json = await httpResponse.json();
              resolve(res.access_token);
           } else {
              reject("Fetch did not succeed");
           }
        } catch(err) {
            reject(err);
        }
   });
}
```

**Client**

```
GetJSON(NewURLCode).then(httpResponse => {
  console.log(httpResponse, 'fetch json')
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: The second code is not working, I get 
`clientWorker.f4bd850c.bundle.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Fetch did not succeed` error. The first option is not relevant for me because of security issues.